# QXcbConnection: Could not connect the view, Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation

I installed wkhtmltopdf using apt-get, but using pdfkit on celery to perform multiple asynchronous tasks, it gives an error of:

> **QXcbConnection: Could not connect the view**

How can I resolve this error?